# Redirect from successful AJAX call in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a web application that I am building that is a test/question/answer app for a teacher I know.  One of the requirements is that the test must be completed in one sitting...ie...no save and continue.  I chose to implement this via a modal popup using jQuery UI.  I have a search page for the test to take and a modal confirmation dialog before the test can be started.  The problem I have is after the user elects to continue the test, it needs to redirect to a new page where a modal popup will be displayed with the first question (each question after will be loaded in same modal popup via AJAX).  I have the search working, along with the confirmation popup, but I cannot figure out how to redirect to the question page.  The Question action in my TestingController gets called and the parameters are correct, but once the View is returned, ASP.NET throws an exception telling me that the first parameter is null.  Below are the snippets that control this behavior:

**From Search.cshtml (this div is the modal confirmation popup):**

```
 <div id="dialog" title="Confirm Test">

        <p>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure you want to take the selected test?
        </p> 

    </div>

@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".takeTest").click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                var testId = $(this).data("test-id");
                $("#selectedTestId").val(testId);

                $("#dialog").dialog("open");

            });

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                height: 180,
                buttons: {
                    'Confirm': function () {

                        var appId = $("#applicantId").val();
                        var id = $("#selectedTestId").val();

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Testing/TakeTest/",
                            data: { applicantId: appId, testId: id },
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function (results) {
                                window.location.href = "/Testing/Question/";
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    'Cancel': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

**From the TestingController:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TakeTest(int applicantId, int testId)
        {
            try
            {
                ApplicantTest test = TestingRepository.GetInstance().TakeTest(applicantId, testId);
                return RedirectToAction("Question", "Testing", new { applicantId = applicantId, testId = testId });
            }
            catch
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Search", "Testing");
            }
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Question(int applicantId, int testId)
        {
            Question nextQuestion = TestingRepository.GetInstance().GetNextQuestion(applicantId, testId);
            NextQuestionViewModel model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<NextQuestionViewModel>(nextQuestion);
            model.ApplicantId = applicantId;
            model.QuestionNumber = (nextQuestion.ApplicantTestAnswers.Count + 1);
            return View(model);
        }
```

**From Question.cshtml:**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ApplicantId, new { id = "applicantId" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TestId, new { id = "testId" })

<div id="dialog" title="Question: @Model.QuestionNumber">

    @Html.Partial("_NextQuestionPartial", Model)

</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                height: 400,
                buttons: {
                    'Next': function () {


                    }
                }
            });


        });

    </script>
}
```

**From _NextQuestionPartial.cshtml:**

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("Question", "Testing", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "nextQuestionContainer" })
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question # @Model.QuestionNumber</legend>

        <div id="nextQuestionContainer">
            <p>Q:  @Model.QuestionText</p>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var answer in Model.QuestionAnswers)
                {
                    <li>
                        @answer.Answer
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

The modal confirmation in Search.cshtml pops up fine and the confirm button calls the Question action in TestingController (verified with breakpoint in VS).  applicantId and testId are both populated with the correct values.  The NextQuestionViewModel is created correctly and the return View(model) is called, but this is where I get lost on what is happening.  I get the exception: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'applicantId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Question(Int32, Int32)'.

However, if I add these parameters to the querystring directly from the URL, the page will load and the modal popup for the question gets displayed properly.  It seems like this is a routing issue, but I am new to MVC and I am having trouble understanding why the RedirectToAction in TestingController::TakeTest is throwing this exception about applicantId when I can see it with a value in the action method Question.

Comment: Wait. When you follow the process from beginning to end, does the exception occur *just* after the user confirms the test at line **'return RedirectToAction("Question", "Testing", ...'** or does the first question successfully get displayed and *then* the exception is thrown?

Comment: It happens before the first question is displayed.  Using Fiddler, I have identified that there are 2 calls to the action method.  The first from my TakeTest action method, and then a second (guessing from the window.location.href line in ajax success function).  The first has the querystring parameters, while the second does not...hence the error.  I'm not sure the best way to do this redirect so maybe it is how I have it structured in the first place.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I remove the window.location.href the dialog does not close, but only the first request is executed (with querystring params), but the dialog stays open the redirect does not happen.  If I add $(this).dialog('close') to the success function, I get a javascript error:  "JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'"

Not sure how to close the modal dialog and then have it redirect to the question page.

Comment: Sorry...another update:  The $(this) is wrong since I am inside the success function....changing to $("#dialog") does close the dialog, but the redirect still does not happen...although Fiddler is still showing the call to Testing/Question with the appropriate params.

Comment: The problem here is that your MVC action is returning a redirect to your `success` function, but your `success` function isn't handling it. Also, `window.location.href` doesn't supply any query string parameters. I'll go ahead and post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest fix would be to change your line:

```
window.location.href = "/Testing/Question/";
```

to the following:

```
window.location.href = "/Testing/Question?applicantId=" + appId + "&testId=" + id;
```

**EDIT:**

After the user user confirms that he/she wants to take the test, you can either:

1. Redirect the page and replace its contents in their entirety.
2. Replace a portion of the page with the test's first question.

Based on your question, I'm assuming you're going with #1. This way, after the user confirms, the browser will be redirected to a URL similar to http://YourSite.com/Testing/Question?applicantId=123&testId=456" rather than staying at "http://YourSite.com/TestPage".

The best way I can think to accomplish this is with a simple HTML form, bypassing the `$.ajax` call completely. It looks like you have two elements you're referencing with jQuery, known by the ids 'applicantId' and 'selectedTestId'. I'm not sure how you're assigning values to those elements, but you could wrap them in a form like so:

```
<form id="testForm" action="/Testing/TakeTest" method="post">
    <!-- Put your two elements here -->
    <!-- For example: -->
    <input id="applicantId" name="applicantId" type="hidden" />
    <input id="selectedTestId" name="testId" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

**Note:** Notice how the `name` attribute of the inputs above correspond to the names of the parameters in your `Question` action method.
Then you could replace your entire `$.ajax` call with the following:

```
$('#testForm').submit();
```

By default, this will submit your data to your `TestPage` POST action, which in turn redirects your browser to '/Testing/Question...' and renders the new page.

**Summary**: Since you don't want to simply replace a portion of the page, avoid an ajax call and just use a form to submit your data.

Comment: Thanks William.  This does indeed work, and if I remove the RedirectToAction from TakeTest the call is only made once which is also good.  I will accept your answer regardless, but I do have a question about your response.  When I see "The quickest...", that leads me to believe there is likely a better way to achieve this.  In my situation, is it best to redirect from the server and somehow handle that in the success function or to build the redirect as you have in your answer?  Just want to make sure I am learning the best way to do it as I am under no time crunch...appreciate your time.

Comment: You bet! It really depends on exactly what you want to happen when the user agrees to take the test after clicking "Confirm." I'll edit my answer to cover this.

Comment: Thanks...the best way I could think to accomplish the requirement was to use modal dialogs.  I have another req that the test can be taken multiple times, but only once in a 3 month period.  Therefore, the confirmation is used to ensure they want to start the test.  What I was trying to do was have the dialog pop up from Search.csthml when a test is selected (ie...Take Test? link).  I thought it was best to redirect to another page (Question.cshtml) then display a new modal dialog with the questions.  When a question is answered, the dialog will call to get a new question via another AJAX call

Comment: Sorry...ran out of room.  Your current answer works just fine, I was just curious if there was a better design.  I'm a WinForms guy trying to convert so just want to make sure I am doing things "properly".   :)

Comment: I just updated my answer. If any of it's unclear or if you want me to expand on anything, please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Sweet...got this version working too and seems like a better approach than the AJAX method I was using because of the proximity of the redirect (ie...at the server rather than the client success method).

Thanks again for your time William...much appreciated.